# Making a Pivot Table in a SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four tables in the database that I am trying to pull data from; a, b, c, d.

For each of these tables I want to pull count(distinct PolicyNumber) and InvestmentCode.

I would like my output to look something like this: (with 1,2,3,4,5 being the InvestmentCode)

```
  a_PolicyCount           b_PolicyCount         c_PolicyCount      d_PolicyCount
1        14                    56                     32                  74
2        36                    41                     25                  97
3        45                    98                     10                   2
4        12                    16                     13                   5
5        41                    22                     36                   4
```

I have tried a couple different ways but I keep getting errors. This is the code I have so far:

```
Select
    (Select count(distinct PolicyNumber), InvestmentCode
        from (Select distinct PolicyNumber, Investmentcode
            from a
        ) as a
            group by InvestmentCode
    ) as a,
    (Select count(distinct PolicyNumber), InvestmentCode
        from (Select count(distinct PolicyNumber), InvestmentCode
            from b
            ) as b
            group by InvestmentCode
    ) as b,
    (Select count(distinct PolicyNumber), InvestmentCode
        from (Select distinct PolicyNumber, InvestmentCode
            from c
            ) as c
            group by InvestmentCode
    ) as c,
    (Select count(distinct PolicyNumber), InvestmentCode
        from (Select distinct PolicyNumber, InvestmentCode
            from d
            ) as d
            group by InvestmentCode
    ) as d;
```

I am just starting to learn SQL so thank you in advance for your answer. I am not sure if it is best to use a Pivot table or by using Joins

Comment: GROUP BY and DISTINCT do not go hand in hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest `union all` and `group by`:

```
select Investmentcode,
       sum(case when which = 'INDCONEX' then cnt end) as INDCONEX,
       sum(case when which = 'INTCRDEX' then cnt end) as INTCRDEX,
       sum(case when which = 'RACT1CR1_01' then cnt end) as RACT1CR1_01,
       sum(case when which = 'RACT3CR1_01' then cnt end) as RACT3CR1_01
from ((Select Investmentcode, count(distinct PolicyNumber) as cnt, 'INDCONEX' as which
       from INDCONEX
       where RunDate = '20200531'
       group by InvestmentCode 
      ) union all
      (Select Investmentcode, count(distinct PolicyNumber) as cnt, 'INTCRDEX' as which
       from INTCRDEX
       where RunDate = '20200531'
       group by InvestmentCode 
      ) union all
      (Select Investmentcode, count(distinct PolicyNumber) as cnt, 'RACT1CR1_01' as which
       from RACT1CR1_01
       where RunDate = '20200531'
       group by InvestmentCode 
      ) union all
      (Select Investmentcode, count(distinct PolicyNumber) as cnt, 'RACT3CR1_01' as which
       from RACT3CR1_01
       where RunDate = '20200531'
       group by InvestmentCode 
      )
     ) x
group by Investmentcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "dirty" pivots an un-pivots are easier to write and outperform a traditional pivot/unpivot. Here is one way to do that. You can achieve the same thing with a PIVOT statement.

```
DECLARE @RunDate NVARCHAR(50)='20200531'

SELECT
    Investmentcode,
    INDCONEX_Count      = COUNT(CASE WHEN InvestmentType ='INDCONEX' THEN PolicyNumber ELSE NULL END),
    INTCRDEX_Count      = COUNT(CASE WHEN InvestmentType ='INTCRDEX' THEN PolicyNumber ELSE NULL END),
    RACT1CR1_01_Count   = COUNT(CASE WHEN InvestmentType ='RACT1CR1_01' THEN PolicyNumber ELSE NULL END),
    RACT3CR1_01_Count   = COUNT(CASE WHEN InvestmentType ='RACT3CR1_01' THEN PolicyNumber ELSE NULL END)
FROM
(
    Select InvestmentType = 'INDCONEX', PolicyNumber, Investmentcode from INDCONEX where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'INTCRDEX', PolicyNumber, Investmentcode from INTCRDEX where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'RACT1CR1_01', PolicyNumber, Investmentcode from RACT1CR1_01 where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'RACT3CR1_01', PolicyNumber, Investmentcode from RACT3CR1_01 where RunDate = @RunDate
)AS X
GROUP BY
    InvestmentType ,
    Investmentcode
```

Using a PIVOT

```
DECLARE @RunDate NVARCHAR(50)='20200531'

SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    Select InvestmentType = 'INDCONEX', PolicyNumber, Investmentcode from INDCONEX where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'INTCRDEX', PolicyNumber, Investmentcode from INTCRDEX where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'RACT1CR1_01', PolicyNumber, Investmentcode from RACT1CR1_01 where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'RACT3CR1_01', PolicyNumber, Investmentcode from RACT3CR1_01 where RunDate = @RunDate
)AS X
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(PolicyNumber) FOR InvestmentType IN(INDCONEX,INTCRDEX,RACT1CR1_01,RACT3CR1_01)
)
AS PV
```

Grouping each UNION'ed statement in the Sub-query may prove more performant depending on the size of the tables. If you turn on "Include Actual Query Plan" you can see the differences.

**Actually, it is showing the first two queries above to outperform with 12% of total cost .vs 77% against the queries below.** With both queries above drawing an identical plan.

```
SELECT
    Investmentcode,
    INDCONEX_Count      = CASE WHEN InvestmentType ='INDCONEX' THEN PolicyCount ELSE NULL END,
    INTCRDEX_Count      = CASE WHEN InvestmentType ='INTCRDEX' THEN PolicyCount ELSE NULL END,
    RACT1CR1_01_Count   = CASE WHEN InvestmentType ='RACT1CR1_01' THEN PolicyCount ELSE NULL END,
    RACT3CR1_01_Count   = CASE WHEN InvestmentType ='RACT3CR1_01' THEN PolicyCount ELSE NULL END
FROM
(
    Select InvestmentType = 'INDCONEX', PolicyCount=COUNT(PolicyNumber), Investmentcode from INDCONEX GROUP BY Investmentcode where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'INTCRDEX', PolicyCount=COUNT(PolicyNumber), Investmentcode from INTCRDEX GROUP BY Investmentcode where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'RACT1CR1_01', PolicyCount=COUNT(PolicyNumber), Investmentcode from RACT1CR1_01 GROUP BY Investmentcode where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'RACT3CR1_01', PolicyCount=COUNT(PolicyNumber), Investmentcode from RACT3CR1_01 GROUP BY Investmentcode where RunDate = @RunDate
)AS X


SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    Select InvestmentType = 'INDCONEX', PolicyCount=COUNT(PolicyNumber), Investmentcode from INDCONEX GROUP BY  Investmentcode where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'INTCRDEX', PolicyCount=COUNT(PolicyNumber), Investmentcode from INTCRDEX GROUP BY  Investmentcode where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'RACT1CR1_01', PolicyCount=COUNT(PolicyNumber), Investmentcode from RACT1CR1_01 GROUP BY  Investmentcode where RunDate = @RunDate
    UNION
    Select InvestmentType = 'RACT3CR1_01', PolicyCount=COUNT(PolicyNumber), Investmentcode from RACT3CR1_01 GROUP BY  Investmentcode where RunDate = @RunDate
)AS X
PIVOT
(
    MAX(PolicyCount) FOR InvestmentType IN(INDCONEX,INTCRDEX,RACT1CR1_01,RACT3CR1_01)
)
AS PV
```